# Android - How to pick an image from gallery, and save it for later use?

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-gallery

I'm currently learning android and I am making a contacts-like application.

The user can create a contact and it will be added to an sql lite database currently.

I want to be able to add an option where an image can be selected from gallery when creating/editing a contact.

How would I go about selecting an image from the phone's gallery, and then saving that image's location to that individual contact so it can be displayed later on?

Answer (score 0):

Use this intent to launch image picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 9000);
```

Use this to retrieve image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 9000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galpic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}
```

In order to save image convert image to byte array and then save to db. bitmap is the bitmap object containing image

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
 String string_file = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```